# get r, g, b component of a color in rgb() format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I am getting "rgb(18, 115, 224)" from a dom element. Now I want to assign the color(whatever i am getting from this element) to a span element. So I need hexadecimal equivalent of the color I am getting. For this I can use

```
"#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b)
```

but, My question here's how can I get the r, g,b component values from "rgb(18, 115, 224)"

Comment: UM, why can't you just assign the rgb? Assignment does not have to be done in hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want to assign the color(whatever i am getting from this element) to a span element.

No you don't, you can just use `rgb(18, 115, 224)` directly for a color value in CSS. (But see below for how to get the hex if you really needed it.) Gratuitous example:

```js
$("#the-span").css("color", "rgb(18, 115, 224)");
```

```html
<span id="the-span">I'm the span</span>
```

Or without jQuery, just for others who find this later:

```js
document.getElementById("the-span").style.color = "rgb(18, 115, 224)";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="the-span">I'm the span</span>
```

---

But let's assume you *do* need the hex for some reason:

```js
function getRGB(str) {
    var result = /rgb\((\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*(?:,\s*\d+\s*)?\)/.exec(str);
    if (result) {
        return "#" +
               toHex(+result[1], 2) +
               toHex(+result[2], 2) +
               toHex(+result[3], 2);
    }
    return undefined;
}

// Note that this is a simplistic toHex appropriate only for this, not negatives or fractionals
function toHex(num, min) {
    var hex = num.toString(16);
    while (hex.length < (min || 0)) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }
    return hex;
}

function test(str) {
    display(str + " => " + getRGB(str));
}

test("rgb(18, 115, 224)");
test("rgb(18, 115, 224, 50)");

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

That allows for the possibility of a fourth (alpha) argument, which we ignore.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it to anything.  If you want to assign this value to a span colour, then simply do:

```
var clr = "rgb(18, 115, 224)";
$('#myspan').css('color', clr);
```

Comment: And that would be an error. Missing quotes, made the change.

Comment: This is assuming jQuery though.

Comment: @phantom: The question is tagged `jquery`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right!  Apologies.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, you jumped ahead of me to add the quotes - thanks :)